# PHP conflict with while and mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php

Here's my code, I have a problem with while, because when I run it in WAMP, this happens:

> Warning: Mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

([Full error](http://spectrum-solaris.meximas.com/stack3.PNG)).

```
    <?php
    mysql_select_db("spectrum-solaris",$conex);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,tittle,body FROM articles ORDER BY id             DESC",$conex);
    $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($row > 0 ){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    ?>
    <div class ="tematica" >
    <p>
    <small>Published by <b><a href="user.php"><?= $row['name'] ?></a></b></small>
    </p>
    <p>
        <big><a href="show.php"><?= $row['tittle'] ?></a></big>
    </p>
    <p>
        <b><?=$row['body']?></b>
    </p>        
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
    mysql_close($conex);
```

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: You should really use [MySQLi](http://us3.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: wats the error you are getting

Comment: "it" happens? *THE* it? the one and only one which is so famous that it needs no explanation?

Comment: -1 for asking about an API you shouldn't even be using.  ext/mysql is deprecated, and has been for a while now.  Stop using it, or stop expecting people to help you figure out how to use it.

Comment: In general, error messages should be pasted in _as text_ - images can't be scanned for keywords, which is helpful to suggest duplicates. And there are probably load of duplicates over on in the Related sidebar `-->`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions `mysql_num_rows()` and `mysql_fetch_array()` needs the result resource that is being evaluated. This result comes from a call to `mysql_query()`.

So you need to modify your code. First then use `mysql_num_rows` and `mysql_fetch_array` after `$query = '...'` insert
`$result = mysql_query($query);`
and then you can run `mysql_num_rows($result)` and `mysql_fetch_array($result)`.

Your errors happens cause data that you give to `mysql_num_rows` and `mysql_fetch_array` not resource type.

And i recommend you to start using `PDO` not `mysql_* functions`.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_num_rows`, and `mysql_fetch_array` expect a valid resource.
This would normally come from mysql_query, as you have.

But your `mysql_query` is failing first, as you never connect to your database, in this code snippet at least.

See,

```
mysql_select_db("spectrum-solaris",$conex);
```

$conex should be a reference to `mysql_connect()`

Change,

```
<?php
    mysql_select_db("spectrum-solaris",$conex);
```

To,

```
<?php

$conex = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db("spectrum-solaris",$conex);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you have not specified the error, I'll just have to have a stab:

This code will not parse as it is incorrect.

```
<b><?=$row['body']?></b>
```

should perhaps read something like:

```
<b><? echo($row['body']); ?></b>
```

perhaps.  You have a couple of other similar errors in your page.

Two more things:

1. Try hard not to mix PHP and HTML like this.  Your code is not the worst offender on the site but it will get harder to debug as your scripts become more complex.
2. cHao is bang on the money with mysql_  please use mysqli_ or PDO both of which have a number of advantages, not least of which is they are the current recommended forms.  mysqli_ is no harder to use than mysql_ the only difference you will notice at your level is the requirement for a connection to be specified in some of the functions.

Comment: Your first statement isn't true; `<?= $value ?>` will echo that value - it's the `<?=` that does it. I always use `echo` with a long opening tag, though it really doesn't need to be wrapped in brackets. In my view, modern PHP code tends to use echo without them.